# How to add data from one model to other django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using generics to represent views

```
class PersonRetrieveView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

and

```
class CommentRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

Person data looks like

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "user": {
        "first_name": "Testuser",
        "last_name": "TestUser1",
        "id": 2
    },
    "name": "Test 2",
    "city": "California",
    "status": "NotActive",
    "phone_number": "9876543222",
    "age": 22,
    "height": 180
```

}

and Comment

```
{
"id": 1,
"comment": "test",
"person": 2
```

}

Comment linked to Person by id. How can i add data from comment to PersonRetrieveView ?
Serializers looks like this

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user = UserSerializer()

# comment = CommentSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = '__all__'


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
       model = Comment
       fields = '__all__'
```

Model looks like

```
class Person(models.Model):

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=9, default='NotActive')
   phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Comment(models.Model):

   person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: show us your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Many-to-one relationship and you did not set [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on Foreign key so your comments are accessible through `comment_set` which can be used to [nest serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    
    comments = CommentSerializer(source='comment_set', many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields =  [ 'user', 'city', 'comments', ...]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. After this I got error The field 'comment_set' was declared on serializer PersonSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

Comment: you have to add it to fields

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your `Person` model has a relation to `Comment` models, simply add `depth = 1` in your Person serializer as follows:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you clarify how can it solve my problem?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization, depth would automatically transverse foreign keys , depth=1 will transverse all foreign keys  of  person. Considering explicit is better than implicit, it is much better to write proper nested serializer.